# IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-striped"  DataKeyNames="productsID" DataSourceID="productsObj">
    <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="productsID" HeaderText="productsID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="productsID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="image" HeaderText="image" SortExpression="image" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="productsObj" runat="server" 
     DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" 
     OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
     SelectMethod="GetData" 
     TypeName="productsTableAdapters.productsTableAdapter" 
     UpdateMethod="Update">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_productsID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="productsID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="image" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="image" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_productsID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="h1" runat="server" Text="Add Albums"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="productsID" DataSourceID="productsObj" DefaultMode="Insert">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="productsID" HeaderText="productsID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="productsID" InsertVisible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" ControlStyle-CssClass="input-sm form-control" SortExpression="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" ControlStyle-CssClass=" input-sm form-control" SortExpression="price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="image" HeaderText="image" ControlStyle-CssClass=" input-sm form-control" SortExpression="image" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
    </div>
```

SQL Server table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products] 
(
    [productsID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [price] DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [image] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([productsID] ASC)
);
```

I have a gridview which is displaying some data, I am know wishing to enter in some new rows via the details view. For some odd reason I keep getting this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'products' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I really don't know what it is causing it to do this, so I'm stuck to for a solution. Any help or advice would be great !

Comment: You need to check the `InsertMethod` of your object data source - what is it doing, exacly? Is it trying to insert a value into the `productsId` column? That won't work, since it's an `IDENTITY` column ...

Comment: Where do i check where in the insert method is on my details view ? I've checked my aspx.cs file but there is no insert method that has been created for me.. sorry i only started using c# a week ago!

Comment: Go to your `.aspx` file, put the cursor on the `Insert` name (the value in the `InsertMethod` attribute), and then right-click and choose `Go To Definition` - that should take you to the method that's being used as `InsertMethod` (I would have expected it to be in your code-behind, the `.aspx.cs` file)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for error is due to the fact that, you are trying to insert values into a table with identity column and SQL is suggesting,if you want to do that,you have to enable

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;
```

if you don't want insert values into identity column, you can do below

```
insert into table
(all columns except identity)
values
(col values for all except identity)
```

Comment: where do i exactly add the line SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;

Comment: The recommendation would be to remove the ProductsID parameter from the InsertParameters collection. i

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation i will certainly be given this a go. Will update you to when it's done.